# Nhibernate with stored procedure. Input parameters as custom object

Tags: nhibernate

That how it works:

```
 return Session
            .GetNamedQuery("Select_Question_Group")
            .SetInt32("QuestionGroupId", QuestionGroupId)
            .UniqueResult<QuestionGroup>();
```

Is it exist a way like this:

```
 return Session
            .GetNamedQuery("Select_Question_Group")
            .With(new RequestCustomClass{QuestionGroupId = 1}) // not existent method
            .UniqueResult<QuestionGroup>();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing stops you from creating an extension method that does that.

Something like:

```
public IQuery With(this IQuery query, object parameters)
{
    foreach (var property in paramters.GetType().GetProperties())
        query.SetParameter(property.Name, property.GetValue(parameters, null));
    return query;
}
```

Comment: Yes, nothing stop :) But I hoped to find something already invented as part of NHibernate or its plugins. Thanks for your method - I will try it with some enhancements (read real columns title from attribute)